# Por que, o navegador renderiza apenas o HTML, quando o arquivo é aberto no smartphone?

Tags: html, mobile, navegador-de-internet

Eu sempre codifico os códigos (HTML, CSS e etc) pelo computador (com Windows) e a URL de um arquivo HTML quando é aberta pelo navegador é sempre algo como, por exemplo:

```
file:///home/bruno/AreaDeTrabalho/projetos/exemplo/index.html
```

Quando é aberta pelo computador funciona perfeitamente todos os arquivos vinculados a esse arquivo HTML, porém recentemente fui tentar abrir o mesmo projeto do meu computador pelo smartphone (obs: com Android e todos os paths dentro do HTML estão corretos), porém para ser mais específico localizado dentro da pasta **download** (`/storage/emulated/0/Download`).

Porém, simplesmente o navegador renderiza apenas o HTML e tem uma URL (no Google Chrome) como, por exemplo:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/1/file/storage/emulated/Download/projetos/exemplo/index.html
```

Já tentei abrir em outros navegadores, alterar os paths, mas a única maneira que funciona é abrir por algum aplicativo de editor de código ou servidor local.

Como, por exemplo, o CSS abaixo dentro do arquivo `style.css` e dentro da pasta `css`:

```
button {
   background: red;
   color: white;
}
```

Está sendo vinculado ao arquivo `index.html` com o seguinte código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
   <head> 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
   </head> 
   <body>
       <button type="button">This button</button> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Ao tentar abrir o arquivo `index.html` diretamente pelo smartphone (testei na última versão do Android e Google Chome) simplesmente o navegador reconhece apenas o HTML, ignorando completamente a regra de estilo do CSS (`background: red` e `color: white`).

Abaixo demonstra melhor o problema:

[image: Imagem apenas do HTML sendo renderizado]

**Obs:** O mesmo acontece com outros arquivos vinculados ao HTML como (CSS, JS, imagens, vídeos e etc). E também independente em qual caminho relativo e diretório os arquivos estejam não funciona.

Existe algum comportamento particular entre os sistemas operacionais do computador para os dos smartphones, que fazem os arquivos vinculados ao arquivo HTML não funcionar, quando o mesmo é aberto diretamente pelo smartphone?

Comment: Apesar de [tudo o que foi sugerido](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145369), pode ser simplesmente a forma que chama os caminhos relativos, mas sem um [mcve] na pergunta, qualquer comentário com sugestões é apenas especulação, e não devemos especular, o que deve fazer é ler o [help] para evitar fechamentos, incluindo o [mcve] e então [edit] (apesar que depois de criado um mcve provavelmente por conta irá notar o problema), explicando o passo a passo. *Agradeço a compreensão*.

Comment: A conversa se estendeu e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145369/discussion-on-question-by-bruno-por-que-o-navegador-renderiza-apenas-o-html-qu) - para ler e/ou prosseguir, utilizem o link fornecido.